# Add values into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

This code is reading from mysql db tables and should return few names. But each name is sent as separated string. I need it in one string. Here is code:

```
<?php
session_start();

function prList($REQUEST){

  include ('into_sql.php');
  mysql_select_db("db394771350", $conn);

  $usr = $REQUEST["usnm"];
  $fID = $REQUEST["friendID"];
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$usr'");
  $a=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  $uID = $a["id"];

  $res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friendID='$uID' AND accept='0'");
  while($b=mysql_fetch_array($res1)){
    $fuID = $b["userID"];

    $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$fuID'");

    while($c=mysql_fetch_array($res2)){

      $usrn = $c["username"];
      $array = array("$usrn");
      encode($array);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This is output:

```
["rhys"]["alexroan"]["bobjosh"]["xc.j.gingex"]["tom"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the function `encode` defined?
I would suggest replacing `$array = array("$usrn");` by `$array[] = $c["username"]` and at the end just implode all entries into one string via `` `$string = implode($array) ``

Comment: this is what it returns:
"ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray"

Comment: any idea how to put space between each record?

Comment: Yesh sure, simply use `implode(' ', $array)`, nothing easier than that :) Why not upvoting my answer than? :)

Comment: would love to but my reputation is not above 15 so far so I can't. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
$usrn = "";
while($c=mysql_fetch_array($res2)){

$usrn .= $c["username"];
}
echo $usrn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just concatenate results ?

```
$result = "";
$i = false;
while ($c=mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
   if ($i)
      $result .= ' ';
   $result .= $c["username"];
   $i = true;
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: not working returning this:
 ["rhys"]["rhysalexroan"]["rhysalexroanbobjosh"]["rhysalexroanbobjoshxc.j.gingex"]["rhysalexroanbobjoshxc.j.gingextom"]

Comment: The last string between brackets is the result you expect ? If it is, display the result at the exit of the loop not inside.

Comment: Thank you anyway solution from @Alexandrew solved my problem , but as I said thank you.

Comment: no problem. For your spaces problem try this: implode(' ', $array) instead of implode($array)

Comment: With a space between the quotes

Comment: that hellped a lot but I have one more problem, in another one we sending a lot of position attributes in one string but at the beginning of the string I need something to appear, but just that once, just at the beginning that huge string. Any ide? In this example it would look like this: "type":"accpept_friends" "friends":"rhys alexroan bobjosh xc.j.gingex tom"
but what I have so far is this: "rhys alexroan bobjosh xc.j.gingex tom"

Comment: when you set your result like this result = "", just put between the quotes the string you want, it will prepend the names string you build just after.

Comment: Else you can do it afterwards: $result2 = "friends:" . $result;

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out may be helpfule forl**

FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)

Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
        -> 2